# Getting null object reference errors for Toasts in a switch case

Tags: android

What ever I do, I keep getting errors like `null object reference` when I try to call a toast inside a switch case. The class where the switch method is in extends FragmentActivity

I have tried to extends Fragment/v4. and Activity without succses.
I also tried to pass the `getContext, getBaseContext, getAppliction();, getApplication().getBaseContext etc` as context to the toast without succses

if I create a public Toast object in my MainActivity and use it like this `MainActivity.copyToast.show();` It work, but this solution dosen't look good.

I want to keep it in one line like this: `Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Copied to clipboard.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

**The whole class:**

```
public class CustomTextSelectionMenu extends Fragment implements android.view.ActionMode.Callback {



@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    menu.removeItem(android.R.id.selectAll);
    menu.removeItem(android.R.id.paste);



    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onActionItemClicked(android.view.ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {

    int selectionStart = editText.getSelectionStart();
    int selectionEnd = editText.getSelectionEnd();

    if (selectionEnd > selectionStart) {
        Spannable str = editText.getText();
        boolean exists = false;
        StyleSpan[] styleSpans;

        switch (item.getItemId()) {


            //--------------------COPY----------------------------
            case android.R.id.copy:
                CharSequence charSequence =   editText.getText().subSequence(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("simple text", charSequence);
                MainActivity.clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);



                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),  "Copied to clipboard.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //MainActivity.copyToast.show();
                break;

            //--------------------BOLD----------------------------
            case R.id.bold:

                styleSpans = str.getSpans(selectionStart, selectionEnd, StyleSpan.class);

                // If the selected text-part already has BOLD style on it, then
                // we need to disable it
                for (int i = 0; i < styleSpans.length; i++) {
                    if (styleSpans[i].getStyle() == android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD) {
                        str.removeSpan(styleSpans[i]);
                        exists = true;
                    }
                }

                // Else we set BOLD style on it
                if (!exists) {
                    str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), selectionStart, selectionEnd,
                            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                }

                editText.setSelection(selectionStart, selectionEnd);



                break;     

        }
    }
    return true;

}


@Override
public void onDestroyActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode) {


}

}
```

**STACKTRACE:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:110)
at org.m.muddzboy.QuoteCreator.CustomTextSelectionMenu.onActionItemClicked(CustomTextSelectionMenu.java:182)
at android.widget.Editor$SelectionActionModeCallback.onActionItemClicked(Editor.java:3228)
```

**Line 182 points to this:**

`Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Copied to clipboard.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: is it your code inside fragment  ?

Comment: this.getApplicationContext() instead of this ...... try getActivity() as a context

Comment: Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Copied to clipboard.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: ....why on earth are you storing your EditTexts in static variables???

Comment: @CapDroid this code is inside a custom  SelectionActionModeCallback class. 

the getActivity don't work

Comment: @Muddz you can pass context reference using constructor of that custom class and use that context for show Toast.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Where can you se static edittext in the code?

Comment: @Muddz nope, show me your whole code

Comment: @CapDroid Its updated now

Comment: @Muddz still getting error using getActivity() ?

Comment: `MainActivity.blahblah`

Comment: @CapDroid Yes:`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference`

@EpicPandaForce I know, its not pretty, but this will be fixed later

Comment: What is your main problem??? First you  said about `Toast` problem and Now you said you got totally different exception like above comment?

Comment: @ChiragSavsani My main problem is that my toast in the switch case Copy: wont work!

Answer (score 6):

Toast method can cause many issues  we must take care of it this why I answer this question.

first context called be null and crash your app like in your case .

how to fix it : on create method keep reference from context

```
private Context mContext;

 @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     mContext = getActivity()
}
```

second when showing toast may be fragment be destroyed how to make sure it will not crash

```
public void showToast(String msg) {
        if (YOR_FRAGMENT.this.isVisible() && msg != null & mContext != null)
            Toast.makeText(mContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

this will keep you away from toast crashes

hope this help

Answer (score 1):

I use Toast in my fragment application like below and its Completely working.

```
Context context;
```

After find rootView

```
context = getActivity();

Toast.makeText(context, "Copied to clipboard.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: it don't work: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference`

Comment: It didn't help in my case

Comment: try to clean the project and re-run

Comment: helped me in a fragment

Answer (score 1):

If you use fragment use following code.

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Copied to clipboard.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

If activity use following code.

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Copied to clipboard.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Fragment` you need to try `Toast` code like below:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Copied to clipboard.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: It dosn't work, I get this error: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference`

Comment: @pRaNaY's answer is correct. Your comment and the error you are observing has nothing to do with the original question since you are getting a `NullReferenceException` on usage of the `getResources()` method and there's no `getResources()` in your (demo) code. If you have other problems, please post (a) new question(s). And please, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it before asking other questions related to `NullReferenceException`

Comment: @Nikola I didn't vote his answer down, I just wrote what the result of his solution was, and that was the error I posted in the comment. And yes my comments and errors has to do the with the original question? People are providing me with their solutions and I'm giving feedback on them

Comment: @Muddz But now you are on different track, First clear what is your main problem ?  `'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference` this one or ` java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference` this one?

Comment: @ChiragSavsani Well right now its `android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference` when I try call : `Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Copied to clipboard.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`